# Unable to find the correct Dispatcher to prevent the "This type of CollectionView does not support changes to from a thread..." Exception

Tags: wpf, multithreading, asynchronous

In the code below I am unable to get the WPF `Window` to be updated from a ansynchronous call. All that is shown is the line "First item". The problem is that the `Window`is not launched from a WPF Application, but from a class module. As our main UI application is a VB6 application it launches som WPF elements though calls to a Com visible Net dll. This works very well, but not in the case below.

THE MAIN CONSOLE APPLICATION

```
Imports Window
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim launcher As New WindowLauncher
        launcher.LaunchWindow()
        Console.WriteLine("Press a key to continue...")
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

THE WPF WINDOW LAUNCHER

```
Imports Window

Public Class WindowLauncher

    Public Sub LaunchWindow()
        Dim model As New ViewModel
        Dim window As New DisplayWindow
        model.Dispatcher = window.Dispatcher
        window.DataContext = model
        window.Show()

        model.Collection.Add("Second item.")

        model.StartAddingItems()
        'window.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

THE WPF WINDOW AND ITS VIEWMODEL IN WPF USERCONTROL LIBRARY PROJECT

```
<Window x:Class="DisplayWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="DisplayWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Windows.Threading

Public Class ViewModel

    Public Sub New()
        Collection = New ObservableCollection(Of String)
        Collection.Add("First item")
    End Sub

    Public Property Collection As ObservableCollection(Of String)

    Public Property Dispatcher As Dispatcher

    Public Sub StartAddingItems()
        Dim progress As New Progress(Of String)
        AddHandler progress.ProgressChanged, AddressOf ProgressChanged

        For i = 1 To 10
            DoSomething(progress).Wait()
        Next
    End Sub

    Private _counter As Integer
    Private Async Function DoSomething(progress As IProgress(Of String)) As Task
        Await Task.Delay(10 * _counter)
        _counter += 1
        progress.Report(CStr(_counter))
    End Function

    Private Sub ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As Object)

        Dim text = CStr(e)
        Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() AddToCollection(text), DispatcherPriority.Background)
        'The challenge seems to be to find the correct Dispatcher. Now the property is set from the WPF Window, but the code never reaches the AddToCollection method. `
        AddToCollection(text)
        `This call throws the well known "This type of CollectionView does not support changes..." exception.` 
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddToCollection(text As String)
        Collection.Add(String.Format("item {0}", text))
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() returns a DispatcherOperation object. Can you examine its Status and Result properties? Also, have you tried using another DispatcherPriority, like DispatcherPriority.Send?

Comment: @Tanis83 The problem is that a line after the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke call is never reached. The ProgressChanged method is called ten times, but the code never gets past the dispatcher invocation. So I cannot examine its returntype. Changing the priority to Send does not change this behaviour.

Comment: You say that ProgressChanged() is called 10 times, but that means the code has to get past the dispatcher invocations as you wait for the completion of each Task in your for loop. If the code "stopped" at BeginInvoke() you would never even get to the 2nd iteration of the loop. What am I missing?

Comment: @Tanis83 Perhaps the debugger is playing tricks on me then. The code inside the Dispatcher.Invoke call is never hit when I set a breakpoint there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the following calls:

```
model.Collection.Add("Second item.")
model.StartAddingItems()
```

This seems to block updates to the user interface.

I moved these calls to the window.Loaded event of the WPF.Form (the form holds a reference to the viewmodel) and I set the viewmodel's `Dispatcher` to that of the window there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're displaying WPF windows, you really need a separate WPF thread (with an STA main loop):

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
  var application = new Application();
  application.Run();
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

Comment: Yes, I read about that, but implementing this, the code still blocked.